# How to get the user's Pictures directory in sandboxed mac application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, appstore-sandbox

I have a sanboxed mac app with com.apple.security.assets.pictures.read-write entitlement set to YES. Hence, I can access users actual /Users/username/Pictures directory.

I would like to get the path of this directory programmatically, how can I do that?

I currently do the following but it results in the sandbox container Pictures location.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSPicturesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

//this gets the pictures directory in sandbox container not the actual user Pictures directory 
NSString *userPicturesPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: I reproduced this in a sample project, and could not figure out any way around it either, using the Foundation functions (like you mention in your question) or the `NSFileManager` replacements for them. This seems like a huge oversight. I looked through docs, headers, and GitHub projects, and couldn't find an example of this being done correctly. I also thought that maybe the container subdirectory would give you access to the same files and folders, but it does not.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that the sandbox container Pictures directory is just an symlink to `~/Pictures`. So I believe this is exactly what you want. You can see this by calling `stringByResolvingSymlinksInPath` on the `userPicturesPath` in your example. You can see that these files are really just symlinks to the corresponding files in your `$HOME`[image: Screenshot]

Comment: For the record, this is the correct answer. Just use the thing returned by `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` and pictures will turn up in the user's `Pictures` directory. No need to inspect where you're told to write to, or otherwise validate it. Just use it.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. The API gives you back a URL containing symlinks. Resolve the symlinks and build a security-scoped bookmark from the resulting URL.